# DFP roadblock with two ads of the same size

Tags: google-dfp

My company's site runs two ads on every page with the same size (head and foot banner). When we run roadblocks we want to be able to flight one creative to the head banner and a blank placeholder to the bottom banner. Is there any way to do this?

As far as we can tell the only targeting control we have is at the line-item level. So we can make a roadblock line-item that targets both head and foot ad-units and create two creatives for the line item. But, since the ad-units are the same size we can't seem to control which creative goes where.

Answer (score 1):

Switch Rotate creatives to Weighted (in Line item settings) and give the creative that should be displayed in the first ad unit much higher weight.

Comment: That's not a guarantee as we can't be confident in the order the ad requests are processed or, if we batch, the order of the ad units in the request.